# Windows 7 Home - programs won't work after "sleep"

Tags: windows-7, windows

Just very recently - past four days - when the computer comes out of "sleep" programs will not open, or open and will not run.  This is MS programs (eg outlook) and non-MS (eg Firefox).  Never had this problem before.  When trying to shut down, I have to do a forced-shutdown.  Tried re-starting the computer a few times without opening programs to see if whatever was doing it would be "fixed" by the computer starting up.  Only thing different in the last few days was a MS upgrade (the routine ones the computer pops up with).

Comment: Define sleep better, fully in standby, or just with the drives spun-down? or hibernated even?  When you do the forced shutdown, what is the item shown that is holding it up?   If a program was already running and then this sleep occured, what occurs when you try to do something with that program?   Need input , more data. What is the configuration of the computer?  like the drives type and external items, or anything else you can relay about the computer hardware itself?

Comment: It's the laptop power-save settings "put the computer to sleep" (not closing the lid, just time-based.  The turn-off hard disk is set to "never".  Pentium P6100 2Ghz. For the shutdown it goes to the generic screen and says "shutting down" but just holds there (for 8 hours once).  If a program was already running, it has been inconsistent, but mostly will come up with "not responding".

Comment: much better, i dont know laptops, but so far it sounds a bit like your drive is not waking back up properly. If the drive is a spinner (not SSD) you could get your ear down there and try to hear if that was it??

Comment: Sounds like drive/file system problems, run a `chkdsk` and report back. :)